# Connect my Flutter Mobile App to backend from my laptop with same internet connections

Tags: python, django, flutter, django-rest-framework

ClientException with SocketException:connection failed(OS Error: Permissio Denied,errno = 13),address = 192.168.43.155, port = 8000, uri=http://192.168.43.155:8000/api/login/ im facing this when i tried to run flutter app from mobile and connect to backend from my laptop

what im going to do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the settings of your laptop
2. Move to network and internet settings
3. Try switching the Firewall Settings On/Off

This worked for me.